# Enabling NodeLocalDNS fails

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns

We have 2 clusters on **GKE**: `dev` and `production`. I tried to run this command on `dev` cluster:

```
gcloud beta container clusters update "dev" --update-addons=NodeLocalDNS=ENABLED
```

And everything went great, node-local-dns pods are running and all works, next morning I decided to run same command on `production` cluster and node-local-dns fails to run, and I noticed that both **PILLAR__LOCAL__DNS** and **PILLAR__DNS__SERVER** in yaml aren't changed to proper IPs, I tried to change those variables in config yaml, but **GKE** keeps overwriting them back to yaml with **PILLAR__DNS__SERVER** variables...

The only difference between clusters is that `dev` runs on `1.15.9-gke.24` and production `1.15.11-gke.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apparently `1.15.11-gke.1` version has a bug.**

I recreated it first on `1.15.11-gke.1` and can confirm that `node-local-dns` `Pods` fall into `CrashLoopBackOff` state:

```
node-local-dns-28xxt                                        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m9s
node-local-dns-msn9s                                        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          8m17s
node-local-dns-z2jlz                                        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          10m
```

When I checked the logs:

```
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system node-local-dns-msn9s
2020/04/07 21:01:52 [FATAL] Error parsing flags - Invalid localip specified - "__PILLAR__LOCAL__DNS__", Exiting
```

#### Solution:

**Upgrade to `1.15.11-gke.3` helped.** First you need to upgrade your **master-node** and then your **node pool**. It looks like on this version everything runs nice and smoothly:

```
$ kubectl get daemonsets -n kube-system node-local-dns 
NAME             DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                               AGE
node-local-dns   3         3         3       3            3           addon.gke.io/node-local-dns-ds-ready=true   44m

$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=node-local-dns
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
node-local-dns-8pjr5   1/1     Running   0          11m
node-local-dns-tmx75   1/1     Running   0          19m
node-local-dns-zcjzt   1/1     Running   0          19m
```

As it comes to manually fixing this particular daemonset `yaml` file, I wouldn't recommend it as you can be sure that **GKE's** **auto-repair** and **auto-upgrade** features will overwrite it sooner or later anyway.

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, the upgrade did helped!